# Question on nth term test for divergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I have the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{n}{n+2}$$

I need to know if this series converges or diverges. The solution says to use the n-th term test for divergence. In general I know that means that if you take $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_{n}$ and get any number other than 0, it diverges. However, I'm confused here because of the $(-1)^n$

The solution says to do

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{n+2}$ and this diverges by n-th term test since it equals $1$. However, can I just do this anytime I have something that has alternating $(-1)^n$? Just apply the n-th term test to the part that doesn't have the $(-1)^n$ and if that diverges then the whole thing diverges?

Comment: The easiest way to think about this is that if a sequence $a_n$ converged to any real number (for example $-5$), do you think that the $(-1)^n$ term would ever make the sequence converge to $0$? The answer is, as you probably correctly guessed, no. The $(-1)^n$ never changes the limit from a non-zero quantity to zero, and so we are able to ignore it in this case, since we know that it won't affect whether or not the limit is zero or non-zero.

Comment: As a follow up to my previous comment, I would also encourage you to look at some further reading into the alternating series test which is also useful when considering series of this form.

Answer (score 2):

The subsequence $\left((-1)^{2n}\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of the sequence$$\left((-1)^n\frac n{n+1}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}\tag1$$ is the sequence $\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ whose limit is $1$. Since the sequence $(1)$ has a subsequence which converges to a number different from $0$, it does not converge to $0$, and therefore your series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the precise statement of this test is "**If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ does not converge to $0$**, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges". That's broader than "If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ converges to a nonzero value" because it includes the possibility that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ doesn't exist, as is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You can argue like this: If $(a_n)_{n}$ is not a nullsequence also $(-1)^n a_n$ is not a null sequence and hence the sequence is diverging.